# 3 column card setup with css flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

Hi I'm currently trying to display my cards so there's 3 in each row and that whenever, there's more, it will wrap to the next row. I had set my flex so it would be 3 in each row, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Second, it seems I can't define the size of the card, so the image makes the card too big. How can I fix this?

Finally, how would I set this so the row of cards are centered in the middle of the page (rather than starting from the left)?

```css
.products {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width:80%;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

.product-card{
    flex: 1 30%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding-right: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;

    
    
}

.product-image img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  .product-info h5{
    margin-top: auto;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 120.2%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    /* or 29px */


    color: #363636;
  }
  .product-info h6{

    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 120.2%;
    /* or 28px */

    color: #363636;
        
  }
```

```html
<section class='products'>
    <a href="">
        <div class='product-card'>
            <div class='product-image'>
                <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20190506164011/logo3.png" "https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20190506164011/logo3.png" "https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20190506164011/logo3.png"  alt="">
            </div>
            <div class='product-info'>
                <h5>Original Bomb</h5>
                <h6>$3/roll</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="">
        <div class='product-card'>
            <div class='product-image'>
                <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20190506164011/logo3.png" "https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20190506164011/logo3.png" "https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20190506164011/logo3.png"  alt="">
            </div>
            <div class='product-info'>
                <h5>Original Bomb</h5>
                <h6>$3/roll</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="">
        <div class='product-card'>
            <div class='product-image'>
               <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20190506164011/logo3.png" "https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20190506164011/logo3.png" "https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20190506164011/logo3.png"  alt="">
            </div>
            <div class='product-info'>
                <h5>Original Bomb</h5>
                <h6>$3/roll</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="">
        <div class='product-card'>
            <div class='product-image'>
                <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20190506164011/logo3.png" "https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20190506164011/logo3.png" "https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20190506164011/logo3.png"  alt="">
            </div>
            <div class='product-info'>
                <h5>Original Bomb</h5>
                <h6>$3/roll</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="">
        <div class='product-card'>
            <div class='product-image'>
                <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20190506164011/logo3.png" "https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20190506164011/logo3.png" "https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20190506164011/logo3.png"  alt="">
            </div>
            <div class='product-info'>
                <h5>Original Bomb</h5>
                <h6>$3/roll</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</section>
```

Comment: Hate to break it to you, but we can't see the images.

Comment: Updated with images!

Answer (score 1):

You're adding `flex` to the `.product-card` div but the `<a>` element is the actual child you want to add `flex` to.

```css
.products {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width:80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    

}

a {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex: 33.3%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px; 
}

.product-image img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  .product-info h5{
    margin-top: auto;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 120.2%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    /* or 29px */


    color: #363636;
  }
  .product-info h6{

    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 120.2%;
    /* or 28px */

    color: #363636;
        
  }
```

```html
<section class='products'>
    <a href="">
        <div class='product-card'>
            <div class='product-image'>
                <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class='product-info'>
                <h5>Original Bomb</h5>
                <h6>$3/roll</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="">
        <div class='product-card'>
            <div class='product-image'>
                <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class='product-info'>
                <h5>Original Bomb</h5>
                <h6>$3/roll</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="">
        <div class='product-card'>
            <div class='product-image'>
                <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class='product-info'>
                <h5>Original Bomb</h5>
                <h6>$3/roll</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="">
        <div class='product-card'>
            <div class='product-image'>
                <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class='product-info'>
                <h5>Original Bomb</h5>
                <h6>$3/roll</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="">
        <div class='product-card'>
            <div class='product-image'>
                <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class='product-info'>
                <h5>Original Bomb</h5>
                <h6>$3/roll</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</section>
```